# JOLT Transform Arrays

Tags: json, jolt

I am currently a bit stuck, I need to transform JSON using JOLT but for the life of me I cannot get the data / structure to work with me.

I have the following dataset that I need to transform:

```json
{
  "policynumber": "12344",
  "registrationnumber": "TST001",
  "idnumber": "1234567890",
  "policyholder": "Tst Me",
  "policyfromdate": "2021-10-11",
  "policytodate": "2021-10-31",
  "ispolicyvalid": "Yes",
  "policyproductcode": "TST111",
  "policyproductdescription": "New Product",
  "item_parent_section": "Risk",
  "item_subsection_extension": "Risk2",
  "item_original_start_date": "2021-10-11",
  "item_status": "Active",
  "item_sum_insured": "5000",
  "item_description": "Personal Effects",
  "item_asset_no": "ALL0002"
}
```

The Desired outcome should be something like this:

```json
{
  "policyNumber": "12344",
  "registrationNumber": "TST001",
  "idNumber": "1234567890",
  "policyholder": "Tst Me",
  "policyFromDate": "2021-10-11",
  "policyToDate": "2021-10-31",
  "isPolicyValid": "Yes",
  "policyProductCode": "TST111",
  "policyProductDescription": "New Product",
  "riskCategories": {
    "item_parent_section": "Risk",
    "item_subsection_extension": "Risk2",
    "riskItemAllRisk": [
      {
        "item_status": "Active",
        "item_description": "Personal Effects",
        "item_sum_insured": "5000",
        "item_original_start_date": "2021-10-11",
        "item_asset_no": "ALL0002"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I might have made a mistake in my desired outcome but basically, the "riskItemAllRisk" part needs to be in a array.

My JOLT Transform that I am working on is:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "policynumber": "policyNumber",
      "registrationnumber": "registrationNumber",
      "idnumber": "idNumber",
      "policyholder": "policyholder",
      "policyfromdate": "policyFromDate",
      "policytodate": "policyToDate",
      "ispolicyvalid": "isPolicyValid",
      "policyproductcode": "policyProductCode",
      "policyproductdescription": "policyProductDescription"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "riskCategories": {
        "item_parent_section": "itemparentsection",
        "item_subsection_extension": "itemsubsectionextension"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "riskItemAllRisk[]": {
        "0": {
          "item_original_start_date": "2021-10-11",
          "item_status": "item_status",
          "item_sum_insured": "item_sum_insured",
          "item_description": "item_description",
          "item_asset_no": "item_asset_no"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "idNumber": "=toString"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "itemsuminsured": "=toString"
    }
  }
]
```

Apologies for the horrible code, but this is a first for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One shift transformation would be enough such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "policynumber": "&",
      "registrationnumber": "&",
      "idnumber": "&",
      "policyholder": "&",
      "policyfromdate": "&",
      "policytodate": "&",
      "ispolicyvalid": "&",
      "policyproductcode": "&",
      "policyproductdescription": "&",
      "item_parent_section": "riskCategories.&",
      "item_subsection_extension": "riskCategories.&",
      "*": "riskCategories.riskItemAllRisk[0].&"
    }
  }
]
```

where the values of `item_parent_section` and `item_subsection_extension` attributes are qualified with `riskCategories` first and the remaining elements of the array by `riskCategories.riskItemAllRisk[0]`

[image]